# Help me prove the supremum property.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, algebraic-number-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be nonempty sets and $f$ be a function from any nonempty set $S$ to subset of real number. Prove that
$$\sup_{x \in A} \{ \min \{ \sup_{y \in B} \{ \min \{ f(y) \} \}, f(x) \} \}= \sup_{x \in A} \{ \sup_{y \in B} \{ \min \{ f(x), f(y) \} \} \}.$$

I claim that two side are equal.

Comment: What's the relationship b/w the sets A,B,S and the set of real numbers?

Comment: $S$ is just a semigroup, and $A, B \subseteq S$.

Comment: I don't understand why your formula includes "$\min{\{f(y)\}}$".
Since $f$ is a function, this always evaluates to just $f(y)$.  Is there something I'm missing here?